# PHP won't receieve POST XML data

Tags: php, xml, post, postman

I'm building a service backend that is being sent a "delivery report" after successfully sending a SMS to a user.

The report itself is XML **POST**ed to our "endpoint" with the content-type *application/xml*.

I'm using Postman to make sure that everything is working correctly. I've made a test using regular JSON and can return the data without issues, however, no matter what I try with XML I basically get no indication that anything is being sent to the server.

*(Test with JSON)*
[image: Server response test with JSON]

*(Test with XML)*
[image: Server response test with XML]

Here's my simple PHP script:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8');

print_r(json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true));
print_r($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
?>
```

I feel like I've tried everything. Been looking at past issues posted to SO and other places, it simply won't work for me. I'm hoping for some answers that at least points me in the right direction here.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trying to json_decode XML data.  You should use something like SimpleXML.
Instead of...

```
print_r(json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true));
```

You should use ...

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents("php://input"));
echo $xml->asXML();
```

You should be able to get the information by (for example)...

```
echo (string)$xml->id;
```

Comment: I honestly can't believe I missed that. I've been at it for hours, I guess I really went blind. Thank you so much for that distinction.

Comment: Does happen, sometimes even explaining the problem to others helps to solve the problem.

Comment: Indeed, though I'm the sole IT guy at our office, the other person usually ends up being the wonderful people of StackOverflow. Thank you again mate.

Answer (score 0):

json_decode can't read XML, seems like you're trying to parse XML with json_decode. if you want to output the received XML, use echo (or if it's for debugging purposes, use var_dump, eg `var_dump(file_get_contents("php://input"));`), or if you want to parse the XML, use DOMDocument.

Comment: You and @Nigel Rain above are absolutely correct. I've been switching so much between JSON and XML the past few hours I went blind in the end. Thank you.